# Serialization process constantly overwrites itself?

Tags: java, serialization, foreach, deserialization, overwrite

I'm fairly new to java and trying to do some serialization in my project. I have a bunch of objects called Student and I would like to serialize them. The code I'm using for this is as follows:

```
  try{
                    for(Student s: students){ 
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Jaimee-Lee/Desktop/Advanced programming work/MilestoneOne/student.ser");
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
                    out.writeObject(s);
                    out.close();
                    fileOut.close();
                    }
                    System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /MilestoneOne/student.ser \n");
                    

                }catch(IOException i){
                    i.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The issue I'm finding is that the students array I'm using has twenty students (S1 - S20). When I attempt to deserialize the objects, it only gives me the object that contains the last student to have been serialized (S20)

This is my deserialization code:

```
for(Student student : students){
                System.out.println(student.getStudentID());
            }

            try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("student.ser");
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)){
                        while(fis.available() > 0 ){
                            deserializedStudents.add((Student) ois.readObject());
                            System.out.println("Added");
                        }

                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deserializedStudents.toArray()));
                        deserializedStudents.forEach(student -> System.out.println(student.getStudentID()));


                    }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException exc){
                        exc.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I have also noticed that when I open the `.ser` file, that there is only one line in it. I'm assuming this may be evidence that it is in fact overwriting itself every time as my understanding is that there should be as many lines as there objects in the serialization file.

Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing that is causing the file to overwrite itself instead of retaining objects that have already been added?

Also, here is my Student class for reference:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Class Attributes
    private String studentID;
    private String rankings;
    private char personalityType;
    private String conflict;
    
    private String preferences;

    
    // Class Constructor

    public Student(String ID){
        this.studentID = ID;
    }
    
    public Student(String ID, String grades) {
        this.studentID = ID;
        grades = grades.trim();
        this.rankings = grades;
    }

    public Student(String ID, String ranking,char personality){
        this.studentID = ID;
        this.rankings = ranking;
        this.personalityType = personality;
    }
    
    // Accessor Methods
    public String getStudentID() {
        return this.studentID;
    }

    public String getRankings(){
        return this.rankings;
    }

    public String getPreferences(){
        return this.preferences;
    }

    public char getPersonalityType(){
        return this.personalityType;
    }

    public String getConflict(){
        return this.conflict;
    }

    //Modifier Methods

    public boolean setPreferences(String pref){
        this.preferences = pref;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean setGrades(String grades){
        this.rankings = grades;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean setPersonalityType(char pers){
        this.personalityType = Character.toUpperCase(pers);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean setConflict(String ids){
        this.conflict = ids;
        return true;
    }

    @Override

    public String toString(){
        return studentID + ";" + rankings + ";" + personalityType + ";" + conflict + ";" + preferences; 
    }
    

    
}
```

Comment: One line in a binary file has no meaning since it is not formatted as text and it is meaningless to try to read it as text. Better that you should simplify your code and problem and post a valid [mre] with your question as the problem may exist elsewhere. Also, when you do your debugging, are you sure that the array contains multiple student objects to begin with?

Comment: Ah, I see your issue -- you're creating a *new* FileOutputStream **inside** the for loop, re-writing the data with each iteration. DON'T DO THIS. Create the stream before the for loop and use it within. You will want to learn to do mental walk-throughs of your code, asking yourself if each line of code makes sense as you do it -- also known as "[Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)".

Comment: Ah of course haha, I always have trouble with loops! Thank you for the link too, I think having to talk through it is a great way to realize the issues!

Comment: You're welcome. Consider deleting the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(Student s: students){ 
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Jaimee-Lee/Desktop/Advanced programming work/MilestoneOne/student.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(s);
    out.close();
    fileOut.close();
}
```

You're creating a new `FileOutputStream` inside the for-loop, overwriting the old information with each iteration. Don't do this, create the stream *before* the loop and use it *within* the loop:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Jaimee-Lee/Desktop/Advanced programming work/MilestoneOne/student.ser");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
for(Student s: students){ 
    out.writeObject(s);
}
out.close();
```

And close it *after* the loop.

Comment: You still close the `fileOut` too early

Comment: @codeflush.dev: you're right. No need to close the FileOutputStream actually. Closing the OOS is enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things your doing wrong, first your closing and opening the output streams when you write each record, you want to open it before and close it after writing the data.

I took a look at the .ser file - it appears to be binary, so if you try to open it up an look at it, depending on what sort of editor you use, it may or may not show interisting information.

heres a working example of what you want to do.
it worked fine on java 8
'
package serTest;

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Student 
    implements Serializable{

    public String Name;
    public String Id;
    public String Major;
    public boolean  active;
    public int      years;
    
    Student(){
        Name    = "";
        Id      = "";
        Major   = "";
        active  = true;
        years   = 0;
        }
    
    Student(String Nam,String id,String major,boolean act,int yrs){
        Name    = Nam;
        Id      = id;
        Major   = major;
        active  = act;
        years   = yrs;
        }
    
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        List<Student> myStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
        myStudents.add(new Student("Mike","140","Art"       ,true,1));
        myStudents.add(new Student("Greg","142","Partying"  ,false,2));
        myStudents.add(new Student("Lori","145","Business"  ,true,3));
        myStudents.add(new Student("Burt","157","Eng"       ,true,4));
        Student.toFile("Students.ser",myStudents);
        
        List<Student> theStudents = Student.frFile("Students.ser");
        }
    
    static List<Student> frFile(String fSpec){
        
        List<Student>   Students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fSpec);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            while(fis.available() > 0 ){
                Students.add((Student) ois.readObject());
                System.out.println("Added");
                }

            System.out.println(Students.size()+" students read");
            Students.forEach(student -> System.out.println(student.Name));
            return Students;
            }
        catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
        }
    
    static boolean toFile(String fSpec,List<Student> students) {
         try{
            FileOutputStream    fileOut =    new FileOutputStream(fSpec);
            ObjectOutputStream  out =       new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            for(Student s: students){ 
                out.writeObject(s);;
                }
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in "+fSpec);
            }
        catch(IOException i){
            i.printStackTrace();
            return false;
            }
        return true;
        }
    }
```

`